# ListFragment - Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I got the error "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list". I have tried every thing but still does not work. Thank for your help!

As you see, I have not done anything else. But I'am getting the error:

Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
Even though I have the android:id="@+id/list" line in my xml.

ListFragment-file

```
public class MmFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

String[] datasource={"English","French","Khmer","Japanese","Russian","Chinese"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MmFragment_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.MmFragment _layout,R.id.txtitem,datasource);
        // Bind adapter to the ListFragment
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        //  Retain the ListFragment instance across Activity re-creation
        setRetainInstance(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ViewGroup viewg=(ViewGroup)view;
        TextView tv = (TextView)viewg.findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tv.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

XML-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />


    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

error code

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

instead of

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />


    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:id="@+id/list"` is not `android.R.id.list`

Answer (score 0):

Use android:id="@+android:id/list"

Comment: Use @android:id/list

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Are you sure your xml file has name "R.layout.MmFragment_layout" ?